# How Can I convert Date String as format yyyy-MM to Date with hibernate annoation

Tags: java, hibernate, date, spring-annotations

When I tried to use `@DateTimeFormat(patter="yyyy-MM")` at top of my attribute,

> ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Bad format
>   for DATE '2015-05'

What Can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: this is a SQL exception, it doesn't understand dates with such format, ie missing day.

Comment: The String date in Database is all with format as "yyyy-MM", like("2015-03"), How can I convert this string to Date hibernate pojo

Comment: Did you try "pattern" instead of "patter"?

Comment: your date is saved as 2015-03 in sql database? What data type are you using for that?

Comment: @Walter are you sure column type in DB is date? which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The data type in DB is varchar with format "yyyy-MM"

Comment: You cannot convert to date because date format is not correct. It is missing day in the date. As you mentioned the data type in db is varchar ( which is not date), why you want to convert to date ? Anyways, in short you can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I test, format lick "yyyy-MMM", "yyyy-MM-dd" all working. The "yyyy-MM" format is not supported by @DateTimeFormat. Then, for getting around, I need attributeConverter or wave magic in getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a more appropriate Java type, 
like [org.joda.time.YearMonth](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) (Joda Time 2.0) or [java.time.YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) (Java 8).
For example, `YearMonth.now()` gives "2015-09".

Then you would need a converter from String to YearMonth.

With Hibernate you can use on your entity :

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "MyConverter")
private YearMonth yearMonth;
```

With JPA 2.1 :

```
@javax.persistence.Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
private YearMonth yearMonth;
```