# Criteria ORDER BY date not working?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Can you please help me in solving this problem. I am trying to order the results of an criteria query by date, but I'm not getting the results I need.I saved date in String format,how can i order by date using criteria

The code I'm using is:

```
@Override
public List<Program> getListProgram() {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Program.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));
    List<Program> programs=(List<Program>)criteria.list();
    return programs;
}
```

Results are:

```
01/02/2009
03/01/2009
04/06/2009
05/03/2009
06/12/2008
07/02/2009
```

Results should be:

```
06/12/2008
03/01/2009
01/02/2009
07/02/2009
```

I need to select the date in the format above.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use Dates in a String and not a proper Date type column?

Comment: @Tom its happen accidently how can i sort.Pleas help me Tom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));` before executing the `list` method on criteria.

```
@Override
public List<Program> getListProgram() {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Program.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));
    List<Program> programs=(List<Program>)criteria.list();
    return programs;
}
```

**EDIT**

In your case, if you want to order by String dates, as i mentionned in the comments, this answer is not the proper you can get ( may be turning creationDate into a Date type is the best! for sure).

You can try some code like :

```
static final String DF = "DD/MM/YYYY";
static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(DF);

@Override
public List<Program> getListProgram() {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Program.class);
    List<Program> =(List<Program>)criteria.list();
    boolean asc = true;
    programs.sort((a, b) -> {
        int comparison = 0;
        try {
            comparison = SDF.parse(a.getCreatedDate()).compareTo(SDF.parse(b.getCreatedDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle it!!
        }
        return asc ? comparison : (0-comparison);
    });
    return programs;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to avoid using lambdas, try using this instead :

```
Collections.sort(programs, new Comparator<Main>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Program a, Program b) {
            int comparison = 0;
        try {
            comparison = SDF.parse(a.getCreatedDate()).compareTo(SDF.parse(b.getCreatedDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle it!!
        }
        return asc ? comparison : (0-comparison);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I updated my question  actually i am saving created date in String format how can i order by date .Can you undersand y question.....

Comment: what sgbd are you using ?

Comment: Actually i have a solution in my mind but it s not proper

Comment: Can you help me I already entered in that column how to process sorting.really i am struggling

Comment: you can check it, I used java 8 to write the little brick of code, if you don't use java 8 let us know.

Comment: I understood you are using lambda please edit your code Collection .sort thats rit? i will give you 100% Ok...

Comment: I want Lambda but check  programs.sort((a, b) is correct that one is Collections.sort(programs, (p1, p2) -> -----); rit

Comment: for descending?

Comment: i used a variable to simulate ascending, boolean asc = true; you can turn it to false to obtain descending sorting

Answer (score 1):

This is how Implemented it

```
 private List<Users> findUsers(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult, SchoolData data) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager(data.getExternalId());
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
        Root<Users> from = cq.from(Users.class);
        cq.orderBy(cb.desc(from.get("dateCreated")));
        cq.select(cq.from(Users.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        if (!all) {
            q.setMaxResults(firstResult);
            q.setFirstResult(maxResults);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Criteria are passed to Hibernate and are translated to the certain language. They appear after `where` clause in the `select` so they all the limitations must be set before executing query. Although you don't see it, there is a query generated and executed when calling `criteria.list()`.

Try the following:

```
@Override
public List<Program> getListProgram() {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Program.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));
    List<Program> programs=(List<Program>)criteria.list();
    return programs;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question i am saving created date in String format how can i order by date

Comment: @SymonKt Dates/values are correctly sorted for a String.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, dates should be stored as dates, not strings. If you are working with a legacy system, it may not be possible to change this, but I'd argue that it probably would make your life easier to bite the bullet and refactor.

As a string, the sort function is working because 05 comes before 06.

I'd suggest using annotation or mapping, as outlined [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31616020/892327), to convert your string to a date in the pojo so that it is the correct type at least **somewhere** in your application.

```
public class StringToDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {
  String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date attribute) { /* Conversion code */ }

  Date convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) { /* Conversion code */ }
}
```

and

```
public class MyPojo {
  @javax.persistence.Convert(converter = StringToDateConverter.class)
  public Date getCreateDate() {
  }
}
```